# Send a SIP text message to SIP gateway

Tags: sms, chat, sip, gateway, freeswitch

I am looking for a solution to send an SMS over SIP to my SIP gateway.

I am running FreeSWITCH server and I am using SIP trunking to send and receive calls from my SIP provider.

The issue is resolved when dealing with calls because FreeSWITCH offers the possibility to bridge calls out to SIP gateway (mod_sofia via bridge application)

But it seems like FreeSWITCH does not support sending sms to sip gateway (mod_sms)

I am trying to work this arround by finding an open source trick with which I can send text messages to my SIP provider via the gateway I already have.

Kindly I am asking recommendations to solve this issue.

Regards.

Comment: You need to specify how your gateway expects you to send SMS messages.

Comment: The question is rather how to route the SMS message to the gateway. I do as follows with calls and it works very fine

<extension name="iptel-outbound">    
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^(89876543210\d{2})$">
          <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/iptel/$1"/>
        </condition>
      </extension>

Comment: The problem is I can't find a way to route Text Messages to the gateway as it is the case with calls thanks to the bridge application.

Answer (score 0):

Often, gateways use SMPP protocol to send/receive SMS. I recommend you check the possibility of sending SMS via SMPP to your gateway.